# How to divide and split an arc into specific lengths?

Tags: qgis, length

I have an arc shapefile for a city which represents the rail road route. It is a single attribute arc that I would like to separate into segments of 90 ft.

For example, if the standard track length for my railroad is 90 ft and the length of the route is 9000 ft, I would like to have 100 attributes, head to tail, in a single arc but with separate attributes.

Is this possible in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GRASS plugin under QGIS to split the polyline by specific length. There is a tool "v.split.length - Split lines to shorter segments by length" that can do exactly what you asking, as you can see below, however, you have to make sure that your projection uses feet units, so you can use the value 90 directly, otherwise you have to do some unit conversion if the units in meter.

[image]