# How to slice a long track into 100km segments?

Tags: gps-track-editor

I'd like to slice a single-segment, 1,000km-track into 100km segments.

I tried the following applications, to no avail:

- GpsTrackEditor 1.15 beta build 141: N.A.
- Gpx Editor 1.6.18.1649: N.A.
- GpsPrune 18.6 Build 343: Track > Split track into segments > Distance limits = 100km : "The track could not be split"

Do you know of any (Windows) application that can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to divide and split an arc into specific lengths?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208082/how-to-divide-and-split-an-arc-into-specific-lengths)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the other question is about how to do this in QGIS and this is about (I'm assuming) GPX files, two very different audiences.

Comment: If available, I'd rather something lighter than QGIS. I'm surprised the above apps can't performance such an obvious task.